# Abstract types and type inference

Tags: types, ocaml, abstract

Suppose I have a module that hides some type:

```
module Test : sig
  type t
  val make_t : unit -> t
end = struct
  type t = int option
  let make_t () = Some 42
end
```

And I also have a function that operates on `optiom`s:

```
let do_work : 'a option -> unit = function
  | Some x -> Printf.printf "Some\n"
  | None   -> Printf.printf "None\n"
```

Not surprisingly, when I call `do_work` on `t` instance I get a type error:

```
let () =
  do_work @@ Test.make_t ()
```

> Error: This expression has type Test.t but an expression was expected of type 'a option

In my application I have `t` more complex than just `int option` and I don't want to expose its internals outward. However, I want to tell the compiler that `t` is actually `something option`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct way is to make only the contents type of the option abstract:

```
module Test :
sig
  type t'
  type t = t' option
  val make_t : unit -> t
end =
struct
  type t' = int
  type t = t' option
  let make_t () = Some 42
end
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But is there any nice syntax sugar for this pattern ? Because t' looks a bit ugly.

Comment: Well, you can name it whatever you prefer, but you cannot avoid the auxiliary type.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to expose your implementation, but you need to make a type compatible with others, write functions to convert to/from these types:

```
module Test : sig
  type t
  val make_t : unit -> t
  val to_option : t -> int option (* Signature *)
end = struct
  type t = int option
  let make_t () = Some 42
  let to_option t = t (* Implementation *)
end
```

Then, when you specifically need an `int option`:

```
let () =
  Test.make_t ()
  |> Test.to_option
  |> do_work
```

This way, your type `Test.t` stays abstract, which means you can change your implementation without changing the interface provided that you do the necessary in the converters to maintain their consistency.

Comment: Good point. I would definitely use this approach in general, but my use case is very special.

In my case I have some polymorphic type other than `option`. 
This polymorphic type is just ID, but it is used to carry some staticaly known information via type system. 
I also have a set of functions that works with this "annotated" values. 
I want to keep internals of type hidden but these "annotations" should be visible to type system.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you want is to make `t` a private type:

```
module T : sig
  type t = private int option
  val mk: unit -> t
end = struct
  type t = int option
  let mk () = Some 42
end

let do_work: int option -> unit =
  function
  | None -> print_endline "None"
  | Some i -> print_endline (string_of_int i)

let () =
  do_work (T.mk () :> int option)
```

As with the abstract type solution, it allows some control of the creation of instances of `t`, but allow to deconstruct such instances (which encapsulation prevents).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the good answers already present here, if you only care whether something is `Some _` or `None`, you can add this to your interface:

```
module Test : sig
  type t
  val make_t : unit -> t
  val is_some : t -> bool
end = struct
  type t = int option
  let make_t () = Some 42
  let is_some = Option.is_some
end
```

(of course you can rename `is_some` to something that matches your abstraction)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could provide an abstraction to allow functions of the right type to be applied as in

```
module Test : sig
  type t
  val apply  : (int option -> 'a) -> t -> 'a
  val make_t : unit -> t
  val ( @ )  : (int option -> 'a) -> t -> 'a
end = struct
  type t = int option
  let make_t () = Some 42
  let apply f x = f x
  let ( @ ) = apply
end

let do_work : 'a option -> unit = function
  | Some x -> Printf.printf "Some\n"
  | None   -> Printf.printf "None\n"

let () =
  let open Test in
  do_work @ make_t ()
```

The operator might be a little bit too much but it looks cooler.
On a side note you might want to look into monads.